# How can you create an event listener that fires only after BOTH 'shift + left/right arrow' keys are pressed simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code below, the problem I have is that the focusPosition function is called but the console does not log the desired string: (`"shift + left/right arrow"`)

```
// Hold reference to the currently focused position
var currentPosition = 0;

// Maximum position we can navigate to is the last item in the summary list
var maxFocusablePosition = summaryList.length - 1;

// Utility function to focus a given position value
function focusPosition(position) {
    console.log("focus position is called");
    $('#' + summaryList[position]).focus();
};

// Focus the first one by default       
focusPosition(currentPosition);

$(document).keydown(function (event) {  
    if (event.which === 37 && event.which === 16) { 
        currentPosition = (currentPosition > 0) ? parseInt(currentPosition) - 1 : maxFocusablePosition; 
        console.log(' shift + left');
    } 

    if (event.which === 39 && event.which === 16) {
        currentPosition = (currentPosition < maxFocusablePosition) ? parseInt(currentPosition) + 1 : 0; 
        console.log('shift + right');
    } 

    focusPosition(currentPosition); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Look for the arrow key in `which`, and look for `event.shiftKey` being truthy to know whether the shift key is down. That's how modifier keys work with the `keydown` event (there's `shiftKey`, `ctrlKey`, `altKey`, and `metaKey`).